# Check if there are users who are using a common password

Tags: mysql

```
Table Structure:
userid password adminlevel
```

- userid is BIGINT (UNIQUE)
- password is VARCHAR
- adminlevel is SMALLINT

How do I write a query to get a list of users with adminlevel greater than 0 whose password is being used on other accounts?

The query result must satisfy the following conditions:

1. adminlevel > 0
2. there are accounts other than itself where the same password is being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.userid AS TheAdmin,
       GROUP_CONCAT(b.userid) AS NonAdminsWithSamePwd
    FROM tbl AS a
    JOIN tbl AS b  ON b.password = a.password
    WHERE a.adminlevel > 0
      AND b.adminlevel = 0
```

Comment: This assumes an unseeded password. That implies the passwords are not stored securely.

Comment: This code will handle plaintext, encrypted, seeded, etc, passwords -- as long as they are consistently mangled.  @BillThor - Why do you say otherwise?

Comment: Properly seeded passwords will all have unique seeds.  This will result in different password hashes for every user even if they have the same password.